# php image upload checking size of photo uploaded not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, security

```
<?php 
 include 'dbconnect.php';
 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
  $target = "images/"; 
  $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 
 $ok=1;


  $name=$_POST['name']; 
 $champname=$_POST['champname']; 
 $cat=$_POST['category']; 
$username=$_POST['username']; 
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 if ($photo_size > 350000)
  {
 echo "Your file is too large.<br>"; 
  $ok=0;
} 


  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `submissions` VALUES ('$fake','$name','$champname', '$cat',      '$username', '$pic')") ; 


 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
  { 


   echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been succesfully      uploaded to return click below."; 
  echo '<a href='';
  } 
   else { 

  //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
  } 
?>
```

My add.php

bottom of my form which triggers the php above:

```
Username: <input type="text" name = "username"><br> 
Image: <input name="photo" type="file"><br> 
<input type="submit" value="Add"> 

     </form>
```

Im uploading images over 350kb and it's not stopping them from being uploaded.
I need to also get image formats & changing the name when uploaded and checking for duplicates but need this working first.

Comment: `$photo_size` does not seem to be declared, you should learn how to works, but if you are desperate for a script, [**check this lib**](https://github.com/simon-eQ/BulletProof) at-least it will be much safer than yours

Comment: Also, put this `$photo_size = $_FILES['picture']['size];` in your between after the 10 line

Comment: Now would be a really good time to switch to non-deprecated methods.

Comment: Simon is there somewhere i could message you about your image uploader?

Comment: Sidenote: `echo '<a href='';` is breaking your code. Either fix it or remove it. It's most likely the/a cause. @Asher Also change `if ($photo_size > 350000)` to `if ($pic> 350000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few issues with your code.

This was breaking your code `echo '<a href='';` a missing quote which should rather look like:

```
echo "<a href='page.php'>Click here</a>";
```

`$photo_size` was a stray variable, that has now been assigned, read further down for more details.

You should specify which column(s) should receive which VALUES, which I changed.

Using `if ($photo_size > 350000)` to check for a file size is not the correct method to use.

Use:

```
$photo_size=$_FILES["photo"]["size"]; if ($photo_size > 350000){...}
```

I am unsure as to how you're using these `$ok=0;` and `$ok=1;` see comments in code.

You have some missing variables for your DB insertion.

The following using `mysqli_*` based functions worked for me, where I am using the entire code inside one file; you can change it to suit.

***Sidenotes:*** There are comments throughout the code for you to read also.

I added an `exit;` for `echo "Your file is too large.<br>";` otherwise the code will continue executing.

**Here is the full code:** (*which I tested and working on my server*)

```
<?php
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');  
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'xxx');

$mysqli = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) 
OR die("could not connect");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
  $target = "images/"; 
  $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 
 $ok=1; // I don't know what you're using this for.

// modify to suit
$fake=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['fake']);
$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['name']);
$champname=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['champname']);
$cat=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['category']);
$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['username']);

$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$photo_size=$_FILES["photo"]["size"];

 if ($photo_size > 350000)

  {
 echo "Your file is too large.<br>";

  $ok=0; // I don't know what you're using this for.

echo "<a href='upload.php'>Click here to try again.</a>";

exit;
} 

mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO `submissions` (fake, name, champname, cat, username, pic) VALUES ('$fake','$name','$champname', '$cat', '$username', '$pic')");

    if($mysqli != false) {
        echo "success!";
    } else {
        echo "an error occured saving your data!";
    }


 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
  { 


   echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been succesfully uploaded to return click below."; 

   // I don't know what you want to do here, but it's not correct. There's a missing quote.
   //  echo '<a href='';
  } 
   else { 

  //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
  }

} // if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
?>


<form action="" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
Name: <input type="text" name = "name"><br>
Username: <input type="text" name = "username"><br>
Champ name: <input type="text" name = "champname"><br>
Category: <input type="text" name = "category"><br>
Fake: <input type="text" name = "fake"><br>
Image: <input name="photo" type="file"><br> 
<input type="submit" value="Add" name="submit"> 
</form>
```

> *"I need to also get image formats & changing the name when uploaded and checking for duplicates but need this working first."*

You can open a new question after this one. I believe my answer has covered the overlying issues with your original question.

Answer (score 0):

you might have to double check your http.conf file that is bundled with your wamp server, check your upload limit